# External Browser authentication using Snowflake JDBC driver

Tags: authentication, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, driver

I am using snowflake 3.13.28 jdbc driver with a Java application. Where my primary goal is to create a connection.

My JDBC url is

```
jdbc:snowflake://<account-name>.snowflakecomputing.com/?db=<mydatabase>&authenticator=externalbrowser&loginTimeout=30&networkTimeout=30000
```

I have Okta as identity and access management system but I don't have Snowflake access setup with Okta. Because of this my application goes into hang state, since I am not able to complete the authentication.

Is there any parameter that I can use to timeout this process or is there any other way from the driver side which can timeout my connection request if the authentication is unsuccessful ?

Comment: There isn't a timeout by default on the browser windows that opens for authentication.